# C# too much memory used

Tags: c#, .net, memory, ram

I have an application that has this feature:

```
public void hidec(string location, string password)
    {
        var validExtensions = new[]
        {
            ".txt"
        };
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
        var childDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
        foreach (var t in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(t);
                if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
                {
                    hidecc(t, password);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        foreach (var t in childDirectories)
        {
            try
            {
                hided(t, password);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

As you can see this function can be applied to many files, the problem I have, is that when files are many (50-60Gb of text file) the program starts using 2gb and more of ram and the computer crashes and lag. How can I do?
No matter the speed, might also use less ram and go slower, I can do?
Thanks you

Comment: That code will use very little memory regardless the file quantity, if you have a memory problem should be at `hidecc` or `hided` where you process the files.

Answer (score 3):

GetFiles/Directories will read all of the filenames at once and keep them in memory, if you expect a lot of files & directories, use [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) & EnumerateDirectories which will load the information as needed.

Comment: It looks like these functions were added in .Net 4.0 (released in 2010). If you are on an older version of the framework (unlikely but possible), you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: I use .net 3.5 and I can not change it for other reasons, no alternative?

Comment: You can p/invoke the functions described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx